# Show image preview when hovering mouse over an image in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been searching for a way to show some sort of preview of an image when hovering my mouse over an image inside my UI. I'm using a QLabel to show the image. Ideally, I'm looking for an effect similar to that of a webpage where the image pops up when cursor is hovering over it (not sure whether this kind of effect is even possible in PyQt, though).

I tried using a tooltip and adding an image to it using HTML which also presented its own challenges. So here are my questions:

1. Can I somehow make the tooltip appear as long as the mouse is hovering over the image? Should I be using the mouseMoveEvent?
2. Can I use another approach besides the tooltip thing? like opening a new window or possibly a separate floating UI just to display the preview? or maybe use a different widget like QGraphicScene

**Edit**:
Here is my test script. I've actually managed to have the tooltip show immediately on mouse hover (it doesn't seem to be working all the time though as there are some half a second delays sometimes).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QMouseEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QToolTip, QStyle


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Tooltip Example")

        image_label = QLabel(self)
        self.path = r"image.jpg"
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.path)
        image_label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(250, 250))
        image_label.setMouseTracking(True)
        image_label.setToolTip(
            '<html><img src="{}"></html>'.format(self.path))
        self.setCentralWidget(image_label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm looking to change the position of the image to center on the label (like a preview as I mentioned above) from its default position which I haven't been able to so far. Besides, doesn't it kinda contradict with a tooltip's nature?
So to clarify, by a different approach specifically I mean a way to show the preview similar to the way the above snippet does it but center it on the label's center point at all times and hide it the moment the mouse leaves the label. and BTW, I'd like to preview videos as well. Do tooltips support formats like gif? or should I redesign the whole structure if I'm to preview both videos and images?

Comment: A tooltip can have a theoretically infinite timeout, as long as the proper arguments are provided for the [correct function call](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#showText-2). There are other possible approaches too, but asking for them makes the question too broad. Start by explaining why your current solution doesn't work well for you, and provide a related [mre].

Comment: You make a valid point. I'll add an edit to the post. Thanks